# Does all yogas include chakras and kundalini awakening?

Tags: yoga, siddhi, yoga-sutras, chakras, kundalini

Does all the yogic traditions like bhakti yoga, kriya yoga, karma yoga...etc involve the concepts of chakras, kundalini and siddhis based on the scriptures?